# laravel5.2 job, how to return data?

Tags: laravel-5

## Job

```
class DataFormFields extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
 use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

 protected $fieldList = [
        'name' => 'Tom',
        'age' => '20',
];
public function handle()
{
    $fields = $this->fieldList;

    return $fields;
}
}
```

## controller

```
public function create()
{
    $data = $this->dispatch(new DataFormFields());

    return view('create', $data);
}
```

I try to dd($data); print `0`

the code can work in laravel5.1 ,but in 5.2 it's not ok.help

Answer (score 1):

Laravel5.2 the class will implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue` interface, indicating to Laravel that the job should be pushed onto the queue instead of run synchronously.
So you should make job like `php artisan make:job fooJob --sync`

Comment: The value of the job is still never returned, regardless

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to rely on the return from dispatch(), as queued jobs can have their execution delayed by an arbitrary amount of time, depending on your implementation. You probably want to consider using Events or a callback.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#job-events

Or, at the end of the handle function you could do something like:

```
call_user_func(['FormFieldsHandler', 'dataFormFieldsCallback'], $data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a list of fields like that isn't really the use case for a Job, as the return value of the `handle()` method is never returned to the calling scope through the `dispatch()` method.

It seems like something best left to a Service, or a model even.

Here's how you might implement this with a service.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

class DataFieldService
{
    protected $fields = ['field_one', 'field_two'];

    public function getFields()
    {
        return $this->fields;
    }
}
```

And in the controller...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\DataFieldService;

class MyController
{
    // in Laravel, the IoC container will inject DataFieldService
    // for you automagically if you type hint it
    public function create(DataFieldService $dataFieldService)
    {
        $fields = $dataFieldService->getFields();
        return view('create', compact('fields'));
    }
}
```

And, obviously, you can flesh out the DataFieldService to get the fields from a database or something. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Simply return the value. Instead of calling dispatch, you can call the job's handle like this.

```
public function handle()
    {
            $a = "return value";
            return $a;
    }
}
```

Now instead of calling `$this->dispatch(new ExampleJob)` in your controller. You can do this instead.

```
$exampleJob = new ExampleJob();
$retval = $exampleJob->handle();

echo $retval; //return value
```

Please note that only works if you do not intend to queue the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get result from async job . when you implements from ShouldQueue interface it means that you tend exec job Async . you must remove ShouldQueue to exec sync job to get result