# How to return data within job in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns, jobs

Hey I am making my first use of command bus design pattern and I have a `**PostController**` and a `**ShowPosts**` Job..
I use this code to return all my posts in **index** method in controller.

```
$this->dispatch(new ShowPosts());
```

and in my job **ShowPosts** , in handle method ::

```
$posts = Post::latest()->with('comments.user','values')->paginate(5);
    if(!$posts) {
        return response()->json('there is no post',404);
    }
return $posts;
```

but I can not return any data in my job..
how can I return data in my job?
what if I have a job for returning posts from a user, what is in that job?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel5.2 job, how to return data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957526/laravel5-2-job-how-to-return-data)

Comment: You should process things in job, which will be be execute when  you should not return from here, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Vikash thank you I wanted to use command bus pattern. so you say we should not return the data in job?? so what about the routes that need the data to be returned?? use controller instead? what's the best practice

Comment: @Caramiriel thank you I did return with --sync flag but apparently it's not a good practice

Comment: you're missing the point of async jobs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm I have an answer for this actually:

**Jobs are often run asynchronously (queued), so returning data wouldn't make much sense.**

Comment: so what can I do to return same data that I've been returning before in controller??